# Ansible failed to update cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, yaml

I am trying to install application on my aws ec2 instance but I am getting this error

failed: [db01] (item=mysql-server) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "mysql-server", "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: "}

failed: [db01] (item=mysql-client) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "mysql-client", "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: "}
failed: [db01] (item=python-mysqldb) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "python-mysqldb", "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: "}

failed: [db01] (item=python3-mysqldb) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "python3-mysqldb", "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: "}

failed: [db01] (item=libmysqlclient-dev) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "libmysqlclient-dev", "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: "}

Here is my code

```
---
- name: Setup Mysql with accounts db and remote login
  hosts: group_vars/dbsrvgrp
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Installing Mysql Service and dependencies
      package:
        name: "{{item}}"
        state: present
        update_cache: yes
        cache_valid_time: 86400
      loop:
        - mysql-server
        - mysql-client
        - python-mysqldb
        - python3-mysqldb
        - libmysqlclient-dev
      ignore_errors: yes
      tags:
        - package
```

Comment: A quick look in the source code of Ansible reveals that [_Could not find the requested service_](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/search?q=%22could+not+find+the+requested+service%22), is thrown by modules like `service` or `systemd`, while what you have here are package installation. So I highly doubt the error is related to the code you are showing here. Please share the full error message.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on the snippet of code and error message provided, the reason for the failure to install MySQL and its dependencies, as indicated by the error message, is that the `apt-get update` command failed to run successfully, which was triggered by the `update_cache: yes` setting in your code.

This type of error can occur due to a misconfiguration of apt sources, you need to be root in order to update the cache or install packages or a missing GPG key required for a repository that you are installing from. By reviewing the system logs, you may be able to determine the root cause of the issue and resolve it accordingly.